# why importer cannot map to custom field type

Tags: 7, entities, feeds

I've created a custom field type and added a field with this field type to my content. When I add set any data on Node Edit page, the data will store into the database successfully. But if I try to set the data via feeds importer, in mapping, this field is missing. I don't know if I missed any hook function in my module, or is there any setting I have to do in my module.

Here, I list all hook functions I am using:

1. hook_field_info
2. hook_field_widget_info
3. hook_field_widget_form
4. hook_element_info
5. hook_theme
6. hook_content_is_empty

Does anyone have any idea about why I cannot find my field in mapping list? If you need more information, please leave me a message. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also need to specify the field mapping details in:

[`hook_feeds_processor_targets_alter`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21feeds%21feeds.api.php/function/hook_feeds_processor_targets_alter/7)

> Alter mapping targets for entities. Use this hook to add additional target options to the mapping form of Node processors.

Example implementations: http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21feeds%21feeds.api.php/function/implementations/hook_feeds_processor_targets_alter/7

More info: http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21feeds%21feeds.api.php/group/mappingapi/7

Comment: I really appreciate your suggestion. Here is another problem right now. After I implemented `hook_feeds_processor_targets_alter` function, I can see the target in the mapping setting. But when I try to import, the data cannot save to my database. Do I still miss any hook function?